# Rails - regexp validation for number of decimal points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a model that validates a decimal precision by regular expression:

```
    class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :amount,
                format: {with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/}, numericality: {less_than: 1000000}, allow_blank: true
    end
```

In Rails **4.2.4**

```
l = Loan.new
l.amount = 1.1111
l.valid? # false
```

In Rails **4.2.5**

```
l = Loan.new
l.amount = 1.1111
l.valid? # true
```

I there a problem in my regular expression that is exposed by newer version or Rails, Rails validation itself or perhaps something else?

Comment: I don't think the problem is the regexp, but maybe a change in the validation.
For your specific problem, you can use the Money gem to handle currencies, it helps a lot ;)

Comment: Just FYI: if you do not want `1.` to be valid, use `{1,2}` instead of `{0,2}`.

Comment: I am surprised that it was ever possible to validate a floating point number with a regexp. Doesn't make much sense in IMHO. That was probably a bug and was fixed in the latest version.

Comment: @spickermann the underlying data structure for the amount is decimal, so the validation is trying to validate decimal precision.  Was doing those types of validations since Rails 3 until this moment.

Comment: Decimal precision is not something you can vary and validate. It is fixed for the computer. Even if you apply `to_s` to it, that does not change the situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Loan
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :amount
  validates :amount, format: {with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/}, numericality: {less_than: 1000000}, allow_blank: true
 end
```

in Rails 4.2.5:

```
l = Loan.new
l.amount = 1.1111
l.valid? # false
```

so this must come from somewhere else.

If you changed your version of Ruby, that could be.

It could be that Rails changed the way it handled format conversion (regex work on strings so giving a Numeric there must be some conversion somewhere). I doubt that though (check release notes).

Answer (score 0):

Could this be achieved with a custom validation, rather than a regular expression? 
Something like:

```
validates :amount, numericality: {less_than: 1000000}, allow_blank: true
validate :amount_has_ok_decimal_places

def amount_has_ok_decimal_places
  decimals = amount.to_s.split('.')
  if decimals.size == 2 && decimals.last.size > 2
    errors.add(:amount, "can't be more than 2 decimal places")
  end
end
```